# Storing configuration info and accessing it from module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm writing an API (a module in `/lib` folder). In a sample app, I will use it to store user configuration data such as `client_id`.

**lib/specific_api.rb**

```
module SpecificApi
 #client_id and redirect_uri will be accessed from here
end
```

**controllers/sessions_controller.rb**

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
 include SpecificApi
 CLIENT_ID = "dlfjksldkjfs"
 REDIRECT_URI = "http://127.0.0.1:3000/auth"
end
```

1. What should be used to store such info: class, global variables, or constants?
2. How can these variables be accessed from the API (module included in class)? I could not access the class variables or constants from the module. Global variables work, but I'm not sure if that's a good way to store such info.

Answer (score 0):

The [Equalizer](https://github.com/dkubb/equalizer) gem answers this with this pattern :

```
class SomeClass
  include Equalizer.new(:method, ...)
end
```

You could achieve the same with :

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  include SpecificApi.new(
    client_id: 'dlfjksldkjfs', 
    redirect_uri: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/auth')
  ...
end
```

The pattern looks like :

```
class SpecificApi < Module
  def initialize(args)
    @client_id = args[:client_id]
    @redirect_uri = args[:redirect_uri]
  end
end
```

And then makes an extensive use of [`#define_method`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Module.html#method-i-define_method) along with the `included` callback.

Comment: I'm sorry for not clarifying this at the beginning but I just want those module methods to use as private ones in SessionsController class and access session from module without passing it as an argument to methods.